# Parsing BING XML

Tags: xml, vba, api, bing

I am having issues parsing the following XML from the Bing API using VBA.  This is the sample XML but I am unable to parse.

Any ideas?  I just keep getting an object required error when running the code below.

**Here is a link to the XML** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/local-search

```
APICall = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/LocalSearch/"
Query = "?type=Hospitals&maxResults=5&userLocation=47.602038,-122.333964,8046.72&o=xml"
strKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    Set oxmlhttp2 = New msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    oxmlhttp2.Open "GET", APICall & Query & strKey, False
    oxmlhttp2.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oxmlhttp2.send sRequest
    Set oXMLDoc2 = New msxml2.DOMDocument60
    oXMLDoc2.async = False
    If oxmlhttp2.readyState = 4 Or oxmlhttp2.Status = 200 Then
      result = oXMLDoc2.loadXML(oxmlhttp2.responseText)
    Else
      result = False
    End If
    Set nodes = oXMLDoc2.selectSingleNode("//Point/Latitude")
    MsgBox node.Text
```

Thanks.

Comment: selectSingleNode Returns a node, not a collection of nodes

Comment: I'd taka a better look at the name of `SelectSingleNode` and see if the problem becomes apparent. Hint: The word **SINGLE** has meaning.

Comment: I have updated my post above.  Even using the SelectSingleNode with the updated code above I get Object Variable or with block variable not set on the MsgBox node.text line.  I have also provided a link to the XML sample.